# My broadcastreceiver is not registering in a multithreading app

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to work with a socket output stream. I want to launch it from inside a broad cast receiver.... I believe the socket is working since the client is always receiving a null value.... But the broadcast listener seems to not be working. I seem it's not even registering as even a simple `Toast` inside it is not working.

I tried to use a broadcast receiver class and registered it via the Manifest. I worked but I don't want that since :

- broadcast registered via manifest stay alive even after shuting down the application
- I need to use some Main UI class variable/methods/inner class (here for now, that class is `ServerReplyThread`). Therefore a separate class for the broadcast receiver isn't going to help me much...

Below is my code ; can you help me fix that ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public ServerSocket getServerSocket() {
        return serverSocket;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnDemarrer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
                socketServerThread.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(smsReceived, filter);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        MainActivity.this.unregisterReceiver(smsReceived);
        super.onPause();
    }

    private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

        static final int SocketServerPORT = 7777;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);

                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    SocketServerReceiveThread socketServerReplyThread
                            = new SocketServerReceiveThread(socket);
                    socketServerReplyThread.run();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }}}

    private class SocketServerReceiveThread  extends Thread {

        private Socket hostThreadSocket;

        SocketServerReceiveThread(Socket socket) {
            hostThreadSocket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                InputStream is = hostThreadSocket.getInputStream();
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);

                //Launch USSD query

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
    }}}

    private class SocketServerReplyThread  extends Thread {

        private Socket hostThreadSocket;
        private String sms;
        SocketServerReplyThread(Socket socket, String sms) {
            hostThreadSocket = socket;
            this.sms = sms;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{

                OutputStream os = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

                MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
                myclass.setSms(sms);
                oos.writeObject(dt2);
                hostThreadSocket.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
    }}}

    BroadcastReceiver smsReceived = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().
                    equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[])
                            bundle.get("pdus");
                    for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                        SmsMessage smsMessage =
                                SmsMessage.createFromPdu
                                        ((byte[]) pdu);
                        sb.append("body - " + smsMessage.
                                getDisplayMessageBody());
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(context,sb.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG); //This is not popping up

                    try {
                        Socket socket = getServerSocket().accept();
                        SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread = new SocketServerReplyThread(socket,sb.toString());
                        socketServerReplyThread.run();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
    }}}}};

}
```

**Below are the permissions of my Manifest**

```
<!-- TELEPHONY SETTINGS-->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Permission needed to read TelephoneManager data -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- END -->


    <!-- Permissions to dial -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />

    <!-- END -->


    <!-- SMS permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <!-- END -->
<!-- END OF TELEPHONY SETTINGS-->
```

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: @PrasadPawar  I'm testing pn my cell phone... I make a USSD request to my telephony provider (ex: vodafone, A&T, etc...)... And that USSD request results in a poppup followed by a SMS... I'm only interrestind in dealing with the SMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the SMS came your app is in foreground/visible to user ? If not in foreground/visible you want receive it as you are unregistering receiver in onPause(). If you like to receive it always define receiver in the AndroidMainfes.xml file.
You can register/unregister in onStart() and onStop() of activity life cycle

Comment: No man... ALL SMS permissions are set in the Manifest... It's just as if the BroadcastReceiver was never catching any SMS...When I put breakpoint to debug, the program never reaches them....Just as if I had never written the receiver....

Comment: @Bloomberg58 You will not be able to send broadcast yourself. It has to come from system. After registering. Try to send an sms to your phone and test. If you are use emulator send sms using adb tool

Comment: Yes I know.... The SMS is coming from my telephony provider (ex : vodafone, A&T, etc...)... I make a USSD request to my telephony provider. (for instance "what's my balance ?")....And That USSD request results in a poppup followed by a SMS... I'm only interrestind in dealing with the SMS

Comment: @Bloomberg58 When the SMS came your app is in foreground/visible to user ? If not in foreground/visible you want receive it as you are unregistering receiver in onPause(). If you like to receive it always define receiver in the AndroidMainfes.xml file

Comment: Okay that was the reason it was not working... But I don't want to use it in Manifiest since it makes it listen even when app is closed. Plus I need to use some Main UI class variable... Now, the working combination right now is register it in `onCreate` and unregister it `onStop`... This works for me... When I use `onResume - onPause` it fails.... Any suggestions appart from what I have do now ?

Comment: You should do in onStart() and onStop(). I have modified above answer. Please do accept the same